# Custom ROS, Install Package?

Tags: ros, build-package

[image: Rosanswers logo]

http://wiki.ros.org/ROSberryPi/Installing%20ROS%20Indigo%20on%20Raspberry%20Pi

After following through with this tutorial I have been able to setup ROS indigo without issue on a Raspberry Pi. Though was wondering how I would install packages from GitHub, or custom packages? I am asking this because the package install process is so strange with this custom distro.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/273549/custom-ros,-install-package?/) by [ethandaniels](https://answers.ros.org/users/32298/ethandaniels/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-10-19

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-10-20**:
Can you clarify what is "so strange with this custom distro"?

**Comment by [ethandaniels](https://answers.ros.org/users/32298/ethandaniels/) on 2017-10-20**:
@gvdhoorn

I meant strange by this command. Im new to ROS and all other documentation shows a more straightforward approach using rosinstall

rosinstall_generator #package-name# --rosdistro indigo --deps --wet-only --exclude roslisp --tar > indigo-custom_ros.rosinstall

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As the tutorial suggests you can build another packages with `rosinstall_generator ros_comm ANOTHER_PACKAGES --rosdistro indigo --deps --wet-only --exclude roslisp --tar > indigo-custom_ros.rosinstall`.

Building your own packages should be easy after this with regular `catkin`.

---

Originally posted by [l4ncelot](https://answers.ros.org/users/23971/l4ncelot/) with karma: 826 on 2017-10-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ethandaniels](https://answers.ros.org/users/32298/ethandaniels/) on 2017-10-20**:
I apologize for my naivety, I am new to ROS. So if I have my own custom package that I create through a catkin workspace I shouldn't have any issues building?

I would just have to run the run rosdep install to get all dependencies then rebuild the workspace?

**Comment by [l4ncelot](https://answers.ros.org/users/23971/l4ncelot/) on 2017-10-20**:
Exactly. Or at least this worked for me.

**Comment by [l4ncelot](https://answers.ros.org/users/23971/l4ncelot/) on 2017-10-20**:
Ofc if you don't use GUI on your **raspberry** you won't be able to build some packages because of their requirements. But other packages should be fine.